# List of List to Key-Value Pairs

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a string which is semicolon delimited and then space delimited:

```
'gene_id EFNB2; Gene_type cDNA_supported; transcript_id EFNB2.aAug10; product_id EFNB2.aAug10;'
```

I want to create a dictionary in one line by splitting based on the delimiters but so far I can only get to a list of lists:

```
filter(None,[x.split() for x in atts.split(';')])
```

Which gives me:

```
[['gene_id', 'EFNB2'], ['Gene_type', 'cDNA_supported'], ['transcript_id', 'EFNB2.aAug10'], ['product_id', 'EFNB2.aAug10']]
```

When what I want is:

```
{'gene_id': 'EFNB2', 'Gene_type': 'cDNA_supported', 'transcript_id': 'EFNB2.aAug10', 'product_id': 'EFNB2.aAug10'}
```

I have tried:

```
filter(None,{k:v for k,v in x.split() for x in atts.split(';')})
```

but it gives me nothing. Anybody know how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close now, you can just call `dict` on your list of lists:

```
>>> lst = [['gene_id', 'EFNB2'], ['Gene_type', 'cDNA_supported'], ['transcript_id', 'EFNB2.aAug10'], ['product_id', 'EFNB2.aAug10']]
>>> dict(lst)
{'Gene_type': 'cDNA_supported',
 'gene_id': 'EFNB2',
 'product_id': 'EFNB2.aAug10',
 'transcript_id': 'EFNB2.aAug10'}
```